# Removing a dup link

Tags: discussion, duplicates

On this question: [How to disclose the negatives of my negative job, without seemingly badmouthing my ex-employer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/112748/3192)

There are currently 3 duplicate links, one of which I believe is not a duplicate. The question itself is asking, if I were to say something negative about my previous employer how would I go about doing it.

The first 2 dups look fine to me, they are basically asking the same thing. The third dup: [Why is it not a good idea to “badmouth” a previous employer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-badmouth-a-previous-employer) while related, isn't really a duplicate of this question. Can it be removed?

Comment: Still a useful link to add. What harm does it do if it stays there?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker its misleading. If it stays it stays, but if that was only link we would probably see it removed. Useful and duplicated are not the same thing.